# AT command with iPhone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, at-command

I want to send AT command with my iPhone app but I don't know how to do it.
I know AT command can use for blockSMS, sendSMS, etc.
Any help?

Comment: Why would you want to send an AT command from an iPhone app? Doesn't the whole  iOS framework provide functionality in a much higher level? Can you give a use case? Otherwise, my guess would be to use C and write to some port device under /dev/ if that is possible in iOS.

Comment: http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/tutorial-send-sms-with-iphone-modem.144432/ here :D Anyone try this?

Comment: If there was a way to up-vote more than once i'd have up-voted again and again.Really good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the iPhone is unlocked you can download a program called minicom to talk directly through a port.  Here is a link to help you: http://www.letsunlockiphone.com/install-minicom-iphone-4-baseband/

This will show you which ports to talk to in your app to send the At commands

Good luck!

Comment: i would like to send AT command from my app, How can i control port?